# Javascript error chrome vs. internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that opens a new window to display the product of the code a user enters into a textarea.  The code works in internet explorer after the user refreshes the tab that opens.  In firefox the button opens the page displaying the product of some code in the same tab that is already open.  In chrome it opens a new tab but even after refreshing the page it will not display the  product of the code.  I'm trying to figure out why this is happening.  Thanks in advance for any help.

The script is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function runonload() {
        return $("#newcode")[0].value;
    }
    $(function() {
        $("#runit").click(function() {
            w= window.open('', '_blank');
w.document.write($('#newcode').val());
w.document.close();
            $(w.document).ready(function() {
                $(w.document).html(w.opener.runonload());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(w.document).ready(function() {` doesn't do what you think it does (and isn't needed)

Comment: So everything after `$(w.document).ready(function() {` I don't need?  Or just delete that and leave `$(w.document).html(w.opener.runonload());`?

Comment: Any reason for using such an old jQuery?

Comment: Correct, keep the inner line, just remove the .ready call. It won't fix your problem though.